# How to install language modules for the glossaries package

Tags: miktex, glossaries, babel, languages, translator

I've updated to the latest version (v 4.12) of the glossaries package on a miktex installation under windows. Now I get two warnings from the glossaries package:

> Package glossaries Warning: No language module detected for 'ngerman'.
> (glossaries) Language modules need to be installed separately.
> (glossaries)                Please check on CTAN for a bundle called
> (glossaries)                `glossaries-german' or similar.
>
> Package glossaries Warning: No language module detected for 'english'.
> (glossaries)                Language modules need to be installed separately.
> (glossaries)                Please check on CTAN for a bundle called
> (glossaries)                `glossaries-english' or similar.

I didn't find these language packages in the miktex package manager so I tried to install them manually. I've created two folders within the miktex installation dir `\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex` called `glossaries-english` and `glossaries-german` and put the `*.dtx` and `*.ins` files of the appropriate languages into these folders. After that I refreshed the FNDB and updated the formats under the miktex options on the General tab.

However, the warnings are still there. Any further ideas what to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, make sure you have installed 
the appropriate language packages for glossaries. 
For English it is [glossaries-english](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-english).
If the warning is still present do as follows:

Change the current directory to `TEXMF/tex/latex/glossaries-english/` and run

> pdflatex glossaries-english.ins

Then change the current directory to `TEXMF/tex/latex/glossaries-german/` and run

> pdflatex glossaries-german.ins

If you then run `pdflatex` on the `*.dtx` files you will also get the documentation of these packages in `.pdf` format.

At this point the needed `*.ldf` and `*.dict` files have been generated, so if you want, you can also delete all other files in those directories (except for the `*.pdf` files if you want their documentation).

The last step is to refresh the file name database, otherwise these files won't be seen by LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Just for completeness after I generated these files I had to run the FNDB update again.

Comment: @user2653422 It was implied...

Comment: Is it the same drill with Windows 8?

Comment: @MarioS.E. I think so, but I don't have Win 8.

Comment: @karlkoeller Yeap, it seems you just need to run the command prompt as Administrator

Comment: @karlkoeller
I am getting an error even with administrative rights: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\glossaries-english>pdflatex glo ssaries-english.ins This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) entering extended mode ! I can't find file 'glossaries-english.ins'. <*> glossaries-english.ins` I am prompted to input another file name.

Comment: @hillbilly Did you download the files from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-english?

Comment: @karlkoeller: No apparently I could not think of that. This is kind of embarrassing, worked well. Thanks