# Language detection for "glossaries" package

Tags: glossaries, babel, languages, acronyms

I want to use the [glossaries-french](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-french) package, according to the documentation it is in the TEX Live package bundle:

> Contained in   TEX Live as glossaries-french

And I installed the packages `texlive-latex-extra texlive-lang-french` in my Ubuntu. So I expect to be able to import it with `\usepackage{glossaries-french}`.

But I face this error message during the compilation :

> LaTeX Error: File `glossaries-french.sty' not found.

Note that I don't have any error using only `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}`.

So I guess that I don't understand how the LaTeX packages works or I don't understand the documentation.

---

**Edit**

Based on comments I remove the `glossaries-french` import and I check the `babel` parameters, and I found what was wrong. But it's still not the expected behaviour :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel} % french is the main language
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[longplural={réseaux de neurones artificiels}]{rna}{RNA}{réseau de neurones artificiels}

\begin{document}
    Test acrfull : \acrfull{rna}

    Test acrfullpl : \acrfullpl{rna}
\end{document}
```

[image: latex bad result]

And if I reverse the languages in the `babel` parameters I got the expected result (no `s` at the end of the acronym) :

```
\usepackage[french,english]{babel} % english is the main language
...
```

[image: latex good result]

The result is all good, **but** the main language is not french anymore. Based on [babel documentation](https://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf) :

> In multilingual documents, just use a list of the required languages as package or class options. The last language is considered the main one, activated by default.

Is it a bug or I miss something?

Comment: `glossaries-french` is a language module, not a package. From the documentation: "This language module simply needs to be installed. The glossaries package (from version 4.12) will automatically load it if required."

Comment: You might have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224083/220875) where the installation process is more detailed.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to manually download and copy the files in a specific folder? No package manager? That seems very archaic.

Comment: It is not very clear from the manual but apparently if you use `\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries}` then the `glossaries-french` module is automatically loaded if it is installed (which it is because you installed `texlive-latex-extra` which contains the French module). `glossaries-french` is not a package in itself, so `glossaries-french.sty` does not exist (and consequently `\usepackage{glossaries-french}` fails), the way to use it is with `\usepackage{glossaries}` when the language has been set to French (for example with `babel`).

Comment: I think @Marijn is right. I was basing my statement on the documentation of the module: »This language module simply needs to be installed. The glossariespackage (from version 4.12) will automatically load it if required.« Since it should already be there, your problem might be one of properly declaring the French language. If it still doesn't work, please do provide a minimal working example so we can have a look.

Comment: You was right and after further investigation the module was indeed installed on my system. But this lead me to the root of the problem. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the first issue come from the confusion between a module and a package. The module doesn't need to be imported.

The second issue is about language detection, it's necessary to give to `glossaries` the good information about the language to make sure it load the appropriate language module.

The documentation says :

> The glossaries package uses the tracklang package to detect document languages.

And the [tracklang](https://ctan.org/pkg/tracklang) package explains that it can't easily detect the language only with `babel`. So, in this case the solution is to add this in the document class declaration : `\documentclass[fr-CA,11pt]{report}`.

```
\documentclass[fr-CA,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel} % french is the main language
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[longplural={réseaux de neurones artificiels}]{rna}{RNA}{réseau de neurones artificiels}

\begin{document}
    Test acrfull : \acrfull{rna}

    Test acrfullpl : \acrfullpl{rna}
\end{document}
```

[image: latex output]

See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56913/141888) for effect of the definition of a language for `\documentclass`.